# Why is Biblatex not working and showing "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item"

Tags: biblatex, errors

I have this LaTeX document `thesis.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}



\usepackage[
   backend=biber, babel=other   
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{library}


\begin{document}

Citing here \cite{ahu61} 

\begin{thebibliography}{99}


\printbibliography

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

and this in  `library.bib`:

```
@article{ahu61,
   author={Arrow, Kenneth J. and Leonid Hurwicz and Hirofumi Uzawa},
   title={Constraint qualifications in maximization problems},
   journal={Naval Research Logistics Quarterly},
   volume={8},
   year = 1961,
   pages = {175-191}
 }
```

When I run `pdflatex thesis`, `biber thesis` and then `pdflatex thesis` again, I get this error:

```
(./thesis.aux) (./thesis.bbl) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.
map}] [2]

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.24

?
```

What does it mean? What can I do?

I am using ubuntu packages installed by apt-get.

Comment: Remove `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` and `\end{thebibliography}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment `thebibliography` should be used only for a “manually typed” bibliography. With `\printbibliography` you definitely don't need it.

So, remove `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` and `\end{thebibliography}`.